# Querying a table for various combinations

Tags: sql, .net

I have a table

[image]

The above table is the master table. I want to devide them based on caption - like all plan,content and accuracy to group based on parentid.

[image]

Need help me with this. Thanks

Comment: Are you using `SQL Server` or `MySQL`?  They are two different things.  Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: Have you looked into Pivot?

Comment: @Siyul - I'm using SQL only. Removed mysql tag

Comment: @roberto - No. I was trying self join and CTE

Comment: @Akansha By SQL do you mean SQL Server?  SQL is a very general term for a database language.  Also, please show your previous attempts.

Comment: Hover over the sql tag in the question and read the tool tip.

Comment: Hi, this pivot is not generating me results as expected. I have posted the question qith some difference. Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849080/pivot-query-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a PIVOT for this.

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ParentID, Caption, Name
        FROM #table) AS t
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(t.Name)
        FOR Caption IN ([Plan], [Content], [Accuracy])
    ) AS pvt
```

Comment: Thanks Roberto, I was using Selfjoin but pivot worked for me :)

Comment: If I want to join this result set to a different table, how can I do that?

Comment: No difference than a table to table join. You can try something like `INNER JOIN #Table2 t1 ON pvt.ParentID = t1.ParentID`. Just add it to the next line.

Comment: I want to insert the result set into a temp table